# Unable to run the project in pivotal tc server 3.2

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-tool-suite, tcserver, pivotal-tc

When I try to my project run on server in STS, it shows me the window as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akqPe.jpg),

**And errors in STS like:**

```
java.lang.Error: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardServer[-1]]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:641)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:661)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardServer[-1]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:638)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol-8080]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    ... 10 more
```

I've doubted that the port 8080 is used by other program and tried [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bL3R.jpg), but nothing returned. What else can be done for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved by choosing only `base` template when creating instance as in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pl5Re.jpg) picture